# How do you insert a JSON document to Solr using Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

There are [examples](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) of inserting or "updating" JSON documents to Solr, however I was wondering how do I achieve the same thing using Solrj (Solr Java Client)?

Or should I just open a socket and send it through that?

**Note**: I'm using Solr 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SolrJ you can either [add POJOs to Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr) using the @Field annotation or [SolrInputDocument instances](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Adding_Data_to_Solr), which are more less maps containing the document fields. You cannot directly add a Json document. If you have a Json document already available you can transform it back to a Java object using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), annotate it and send it through SolrJ or send the request via httpclient without using SolrJ at all.